# How to open two web pages at once? This is working on all devices with the exception of iPhones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The goal is to click on one link and for that link to open a new web page. Then I would like to redirect the original web page to a new page. To put it simply, I want one link to open two different web pages on a single click!

The Issue:
I have managed to make this work using. "location.href"

This manages to work on every device with the exception of iPhones. There are a few different ways to write “location.href,” for example “window.location.href,” I have followed every single trick from Stack Overflow and I am still running into issues. I have tried using “window.open” but this results in a popup blocker being initiated on click. I then thought it may help to set a delay using JS and then calling the redirect, this failed. If you can provide any insight on making this work on iPhones, it would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
<div class="button-offer-box">
    <a href="example.com" onclick="location.href='example_site.com';"  target="_blank">open two pages</a>
</div>
```

I would like to have the link open a new page and have the existing page redirected, again this needs to work on iPhones, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for reading this, I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do it all with javascript:

```
<a onclick="location.href='http://example_site.com';window.open('http://example_site2.com', '_blank')">open two pages</a>
```

Comment: Ahh Thank you so much, it worked like a charm. So what made you approach this from a pure js point. Do you have a deep understanding of js or have you dealt with an issue like this before? I am very interested as to how you came to this conclusion?

Comment: By the way, I just joined, so I do not have enough points to upvote, with the rise in iPhones this will no doubt go up in votes, good work friend!

Comment: Using an `a` tag without a `href` attribute is something you should never do. You should put the link you assign to `location` into `href` or don’t use `a` at all.

Comment: @t niese. Are you able to provide a solution with the given restraints you have suggested? I am all for following best practices, so please let me know. Thanks in advance.